Can you give potions to other players in Slay the Spire outside of when you gain a potion?
Page 8 of the Slay the Spire board game's rulebook states:

Potion – Draw a card from the potion deck. You may gain that potion or skip it. Keep it face up in front of you until used. You can’t have more than 3 potions. Potions are all single-use items. When a potion is used, discarded, or skipped, put it on the bottom of the potion deck. If you gain a potion but you’re at the limit, you must either: skip the potion, pass the potion to a player who is below their potion limit, or discard or use a potion then gain the new potion.

Can you give potions to another player outside of when you gain a new potion? Could I give another player a potion right before combat?

Yes. Near the top of page 8, the rulebook states:

Trading - Potions can be given to other players outside of combat. Nothing else can be traded.

